# How do you use reactive Sessions with pass-by-reference items? (Arrays, objects, etc.)

Tags: meteor

I'm making a simple function like this:

```
Game.msg = function(msg){
   var m = Session.get("messages") || [];
   m.push({"text": msg});
   Session.set("messages", m);
};
```

and a template:

```
Template.field.messages = function(){
   return Session.get("messages");
};
```

Triggering Game.msg() doesn't trigger an auto-update of the template. I suspect it's because the Array reference hasn't changed [even though the contents have]. What's the best way to trigger an update?

My hacky workaround is to have a dummy count variable (var c = Session.get("message_count")) which I set in Game.msg and reference in Template.field.messages, like this:

```
Game.msg = function(msg){
  var m = Session.get("messages") || [];
  m.push({"text": msg});

  // silly, but adding a count so the array size changes and triggers a flush
  Session.set("messages", m);
  Session.set("message_count", m.length);
};


Template.field.messages = function(){
    var c = Session.get("message_count");
    return Session.get("messages");
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using _.extend to create a new mutable object like this?

```
Game.msg = function(msg){
    var m = Session.get("messages");
    m = _.extend([], m);
    m.push({"text": msg});
    Session.set("messages", m);
};
```

I think it's a little bit clear than having a new variable in Session.

P.S. sorry, I have not enough reputation to comment, so I turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. I was needlessly hesitant about copying to a new array, but it should be a fast operation.